# Convert multiheader csv to nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Content of my csv file is::

```
[user@localhost ~]$ cat tempcsv.csv
info,info,auth,req,req
name,desc,username,key1,key2
a,alphabet,admin,1,team
```

Here, the csv contains two headers.

On using pandas to read the csv,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('tempcsv.csv', sep=',', header=[0,1], encoding = "utf-8-sig", skipinitialspace=True, tupleize_cols=True)
  (info, name) (info, desc) (auth, username)  (req, key1) (req, key2)
0            a     alphabet            admin            1        team
>>> df = pd.read_csv('tempcsv.csv', sep=',', header=[0,1], encoding = "utf-8-sig", skipinitialspace=True, tupleize_cols=True)
>>> df.to_dict()
{(u'req', u'key1'): {0: 1}, (u'req', u'key2'): {0: u'team'}, (u'info', u'name'): {0: u'a'}, (u'auth', u'username'): {0: u'admin'}, (u'info', u'desc'): {0: u'alphabet'}}
```

Now on trying to convert the dataframe to dict, I get a list dicts that have key as tuple.

```
>>> df.to_dict('records')
[{(u'req', u'key1'): 1, (u'req', u'key2'): u'team', (u'info', u'name'): u'a', (u'auth', u'username'): u'admin', (u'info', u'desc'): u'alphabet'}]
```

When I try to convert them to a proper dictionary,

```
>>> result = []
>>> row_data = {}
>>> for row in df.to_dict('records'):
...     for key,value in row.iteritems():
...             row_data.setdefault(key[0], {})[key[1]] = value
...
>>> row_data
{u'info': {u'name': u'a', u'desc': u'alphabet'}, u'req': {u'key2': u'team', u'key1': 1}, u'auth': {u'username': u'admin'}}
```

And that is my expected output --

```
{u'info': {u'name': u'a', u'desc': u'alphabet'}, u'req': {u'key2': u'team', u'key1': 1}, u'auth': {u'username': u'admin'}}
```

So my question is, is there any way to convert the dataframe to dict using python?

Or, is there a way to do the same using csv package?

Pandas version:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
pd>>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with pandas 2.0.3

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_data = """info,info,auth,req,req
name,desc,username,key1,key2
a,alphabet,admin,1,team"""

csv_stream = StringIO(csv_data)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_stream, header=[0, 1])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)

formatted_dict = {}
for (outer_key, inner_key), value in df.to_dict(orient='records')[0].items():
    formatted_dict.setdefault(outer_key, {})[inner_key] = value

print(formatted_dict)
```

Output:

> {'info': {'name': 'a', 'desc': 'alphabet'}, 'auth': {'username': 'admin'}, 'req': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 'team'}}

Answer (score -1):

I don't think `pandas` is capable of parsing such CSVs, but you can always use the built-in `csv` module and parse the data yourself, e.g.:

```
import csv
import collections

with open("tempcsv.csv", "rb") as f: # on Python 3.x use: open("tempcsv.csv", "r", newline="")
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # create a CSV reader
    header = next(reader)  # collect the primary header
    subheader = next(reader)  # collect the subheader
    rows = []
    for row in reader:  # iterate over the rest of the CSV file
        parsed_row = collections.defaultdict(dict)  # use a dictionary factory
        for i, v in enumerate(header):  # iterate over the primary header fields
            # update each in the factory using the primary->secondary header map
            parsed_row[v].update({subheader[i]: row[i]})  
        rows.append(parsed_row)
```

This will create a `rows` list containing all the rows with *fused* headers. For your data, a row would look like:

```
{'info': {'name': 'a', 'desc': 'alphabet'},
 'auth': {'username': 'admin'},
 'req': {'key1': '1', 'key2': 'team'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We can parse such csv's using pandas. That is what I've shared above. And yes, I'm aware of parsing each line in csv using the csv package. Is there an option to parse the multi header csv neatly is my question. :)